# FileInputStream read from variable to FTPClient

Tags: java, fileinputstream, objectinputstream

I'm a bit confused. I got this block of code :

```
public void serializeStock(){

    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    try{
        client.connect("ftp.**.***");
        client.login("***", "*****");

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(someVariableContainingObject); // <-- The object ( StockVault stocks = new StockVault();
        ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
        client.storeFile("theObject", oos);
        System.out.println("Wrote Stocks data to file");

        client.logout();
        client.disconnect();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I open a connection to my remote FTP server, I now want to write a object named "stocks" to the server. I know I can save the object file first, and then upload it. But is it possible to store the object in a "file" variable or something, and feed it directly to the FileInputStream? This way I wont have to save the object to an actual system file, and then upload it. But make some kind of variable to hold the file, and then upload the "file-variable" to the ftp-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to stream directly to the FTP server, but FileInputStream is not the right class to do so -- it always reads from a local file.

The simplest way to do this in your case may be to use

```
client.storeFileStream(remoteName)
```

This method returns an output stream you can write to (instead of sucking up all the data from a given input stream), which seems to be a more natural fit for your case.

Example:

```
OutputStream os = client.storeFileStream("theObject");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

// write your object to oos here,
// then close everything.
```

An alternative that uses the same client method as in your example but no file would be to first write the object to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then create a `ByteArrayInputStream` from `getBytes()`, and hand that over to the ftp client.

BTW: The Object stream in your code can be omitted -- you can use the file stream directly:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(someVariableContainingObject); 
client.storeFile("theObject", fin);
// ...
```